# Customizations vs Residue collectors

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I don't really grasp the difference between Customizations and Residue Collectors.

According to [Documentation](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Fixture%20Architecture&referringTitle=Architecture), if I register a customization that can build, `ExampleClass` it will handle requests for that type that **were not handled by other builders**. If I register a Residue Collector for type `ExampleClass` it will handle requests, that **were not handled by any (other) builders**

Where's the difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**tl;dr**
That's a very valid question. The difference between the two is *priority*, that is the order in which they're given the chance to handle requests. Customizations are first, while Residue Collectors are last.

AutoFixture, at its core, consists of a [Chain of Responsibility](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) where each node in the pipeline is called a *specimen builder*. These builders are organized in three categories, which determine their position in the chain:

1. Customizations
2. Engine
3. Residue collectors

Specimen builders higher up in the chain get to handle incoming requests first, *effectively overriding those that are further down*.

**Customizations** are typically ad-hoc specimen builders created by the user to handle certain kind of requests in a particular way. Hence, they're are given the highest priority.

**Engine** are the built-in specimen builders that come with AutoFixture. They handle all primitive types such as strings, numbers and dates.

**Residue collectors** are the specimen builders with the lowest priority and will catch requests that can't be handled by any other builder. They're typically used as fall-back strategy.